# While restarting it shows unknown filesystem error in grub

Tags: grubrescue

I have a multi-boot operating system with Windows 10 and Parrot Security.

With my auto update settings in Windows 10, it got updated automatically and when I tried to restart it shows the error below...

[image: grub failure]

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 3):

To get back your bootloader
type in:

**ls**              (you get all disk partition listed like (hd0,gpt10),etc)

**ls (hd0,gpt#)**   (Replace # by all the partitions listed, you will get all as "Filesystem is unknown", and only one with "Filesystem is ext2")
(let say gpt5 got the ext2 flag)

**set boot=(hd0,gpt5)**

**set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub**

**insmod normal**

**normal**

** now boot into your linux system and repair your grub
open terminal in super user mode(super su)
and type in:

**grub-install /dev/sda**

**os-prober**

**update-grub**

Comment: Nice save. Google led me here. I was dealing with an Ubuntu system presenting the same problem. This answer provided the solution.